# Change Password using MVC5 Entity Framework using code first

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first

I am trying to update the password using below controller method.

```
  public ActionResult ChangePassword([Bind(Include = "NewPassword")] Register ChangePassword, FormCollection frm)
    {

        string Email = Session["email"].ToString();

        var existingEmail = db.Registers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.EmailId == Email);


        if (existingEmail != null)
        {
            //Need to update password

        }

        return View();


    }
```

Below is Register model.

```
   [Table("Register")]
public class Register
{
    [Key]
    public int Sno { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Full name")]
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Email Id")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required.")]
    public string EmailId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required.")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Mobile is required.")]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required.")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Entity is required.")]
    public string EntityType { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }

    public string PinCode { get; set; }


      public string accountactivated { get; set; }

     public int RoleId { get; set; }

     [Display(Name = "New Password")]
      [NotMapped]
      public string NewPassword { get; set; }
     [Display(Name = "Confirm New Password")]
     [NotMapped] // Does not effect with your database
     [System.Web.Mvc.Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "Password not match")]
     public string ConfirmNewPassword { get; set; }


   }
```

Below is my change password design

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

 <div class="form-horizontal">

    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewPassword, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NewPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewPassword)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmNewPassword, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.ConfirmNewPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmNewPassword)
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Change Password" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    }
```

Please help to out this situation and waiting for your response.I am very new to developing my project using asp.net mvc code first and this my first project which i am doing. I am thankful in advance.

Comment: What are you seeing happen?

Comment: I am not able to write linq update query for single field to update password. @d219

Comment: Start a new project and click on the button "Change Authentication" and select Individual User Accounts. If you are new, then you should read tutorials first: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset